# Update Post with Modified Data

Tags: posts, wp-query, wp-update-post

Task is to take class from `<pre class="php"></pre>`, and add that class to `<code></code>` and wrap all content of `<pre>` into `<code>` after that.

I am querying WP with this args:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'=>'post', 
    'post_status'=>'any', 
    'order_by'=>'date', 
    'order'=>'DESC', 
    's'=> '<pre',
    'nopaging' =>true,
    'posts_per_page' => -1

   );

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Then, I am updating data with this:

```
        $my_post = array(
            'ID'           => get_the_ID(),
            //'post_date_gmt'=> gmdate( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', time() ),
            'post_content' => $dataUpdate
        );

      // Return 0 (or wp_Error, if 2nd param is passed true).
      wp_update_post( $my_post );
```

So, if post data is:

```
[
. . . .. 
some content
<pre class="php">
  escaped markup
</pre>
. . . . . 
]
```

Then, the updated post would be:

```
[
. . . .. 
some content
<pre>
<code class="php">
  escaped markup
</code>
</pre>
. . . . . 
]
```

I am using DOMDocument, but the  `tag that get added are coming in this form &lt;code class="php"&gt;`, so it cannot be used with Syntax Highlighter. I thing, DOMDocument is escaping it.

**How to avoid escaping of newly created tag?**

**Is there any better approach I would have taken?**

Comment: I see when I do the same thing through createElement then code element is not escaped but when I update to WP then it is still escaped.

Comment: All trouble was there due to a escaping plugins I have installed to test. So, that plugin was working even when I update wp through a separate code.